# Separate letters and numbers from file into two different files

Tags: linux, shell, unix, terminal

The task is to read a file containing letters and numbers. Then put the letters in a text file inside a Letters directory and the numbers in a different text file in a numbers directory. The problem I'm having is I don't know how I would identify strings and integers within a file.

The file I'm using contains:

```
723

Xavier

Cat

323

Zebra
```

This is the code I've come up with.

```
 #!/bin/bash

 file = $1
 mkdir Numbers
 mkdir Letters
 touch Numbers/Numbers.txt
 touch Letters/Letters.txt
 for x in $file; do
 if [x == string];
 then
 echo x >> Letters/Letters.txt;
 fi
 if [x == integer];
 then
 echo x >> Numbers/Numbers.txt;
 fi
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately, your program contains several syntax errors, like spaces around `=`, no spaces around `]` and `[`. Can you please modify your code to at least run and then update the question?

Comment: On another note, do you have to use Bash for this? [It's not a very good language for this task.](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashWeaknesses)

Comment: What do you want to do with input `foo17`?  Or `%$#^`?  Is the problem line based (eg, do you want one file per line), or do you want one file with all the letters and one file with all the numbers?

Comment: I apologize for all the syntactical errors, my professor teaches us the commands, but not the proper syntax. I'll try to avoid such errors in the future. Yes it has to be a Bash script.

Comment: I want to create two new separate files. One containing all the letters and the other containing all the numbers. The input file should only contains letters and numbers no special characters.

Comment: @Tarracon, Re "*no special characters*": so no linefeeds in the input or output?  Yet the sample data in the Q. has linefeeds, and the accepted answer  uses `while read line` which *depends* on linefeeds.  **Please read** `man ascii` to brush up on chars, (it's quite brief), then revise the Q. accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original code has a lot of syntactical errors. I suggest going forward please submit a code which is at least syntactically correct. 
Anyways, assuming you are new to unix shell scripting, here a quick solution to your problem

```
#!/bin/bash

file=$1
mkdir Numbers
mkdir Letters
touch Numbers/Numbers.txt
touch Letters/Letters.txt
while read line
do
if [[ $line =~ [^0-9] ]]
then
echo $line >> Letters/Letters.txt
else
echo $line >> Numbers/Numbers.txt
fi
done < $file
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is vague.

1. This solves the question as posted, and handles lines with mixed
   numbers and strings, (*e.g.:* "*a1b2c3*".), using `tee` and `bash`
   *process substitution*, with `tr` to *delete* all undesired chars:

   ```
   mkdir Numbers Letters
   tee >(tr -d '[0-9]'    > Letters/Letters.txt) \
       >(tr -d '[a-zA-Z]' > Numbers/Numbers.txt) \
       > /dev/null < inputfile
   ```
2. If the goal is to remove whole lines that are either *all* numbers
   or *all* letters, try `grep`:

   ```
   mkdir Numbers Letters
   tee >(grep -v '^[0-9]*$'    > Letters/Letters.txt) \
       >(grep    '^[0-9]*$'    > Numbers/Numbers.txt) \
       > /dev/null < inputfile
   ```